# El programa parece no guardar la información o tienen otro fallo que no veo

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un trabajo y ya lo tengo terminado pero al probarlo parece como que no guarda la información.

El trabajo tiene 4 clases el main, una clase materiales, una clase parte de trabajo con un arraylist de materiales entre otros atributos y una clase empresa con un arraylist de partes de trabajo.

Ninguna de las clases tiene nigun error que marque neatbeans.

Al probarlo le doy al case 1 en el menú y introduzco los datos y por alguna razón parece no coger la información porque al ir luego  a llamar al toSting aparece vació.

No se me ocurre que pude estar mal, os dejo el codigo y si creeis que puede ser otra cosa os pongo el codigo de las otras clases.

```
public class GestionDePartes {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File miFichero = new File("PilaDePartes.dat");
    Empresa e = null;
    if (!miFichero.exists()) {
        e = new Empresa();
    } else {
        e = deserializa();
    }
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("1. Anadir un nuevo parte de trabajo");
        System.out.println("2. Añadir material al parte");
        System.out.println("3. Eliminar un parte");
        System.out.println("4. Buscar parte por nombre de trabajador");
        System.out.println("5. Listar los partes de trabaja que se hallen pendientes y tengan más 10 días de antigüedad");
        System.out.println("6. Listar  todas los partes");
        System.out.println("7. Ordenar los partes de trabajo por la fecha del parte de forma ascendente.");
        System.out.println("8. Salir");
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

        opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                ParteDeTrabajo p = new ParteDeTrabajo();
                System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: ");
                p.setNombreCliente(entrada.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha del parte en el formato (año-mes-dia): ");
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(entrada.nextLine());
                p.setFechaParte(localDate);

                System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del trabajador: ");
                p.setNombreTrabajador(entrada.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de la reparacion: ");
                LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(entrada.nextLine());
                p.setFechaReparacion(localDate1);

                System.out.println("Introduzca los minutos de la reparacion: ");
                p.setTiempoReparacion(Double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine()));

                System.out.println("Introduzca la descripcion del arreglo: ");
                p.setDescripcionArreglo(entrada.nextLine());
                e.aniadirParte(p);

                break;
            case 2:
                Material m = new Material();
                String aux = "";
                String aux1 = "";
                System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de material: ");
                m.setCantidadUsada(Double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine()));
                System.out.println("Introduzca el material usado: ");
                m.setMaterial(entrada.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: ");
                aux = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha del parte: ");
                aux1 = entrada.nextLine();
                LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.parse(aux1);
                e.añadirMateriales(aux, localDate2, m);
                break;
            case 3:
                int aux11 = 0;
                System.out.println("Introduzca la posicion del parte que desea borrar: ");
                aux11 = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
                e.borrarParte(aux11);
                break;
            case 4:
                String aux12 = "";
                System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del trabajador: ");
                entrada.nextLine();
                e.buscarParte(aux12);
                break;
            case 5:
                e.trabajosPendiente();
                break;
            case 6:
                e.toString();
                break;
            case 7:
                Collections.sort(e.getPilaDePartes());
                break;

            case 8:
                salir = true;
                serializa(e);
                entrada.close();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Solo numeros entre 1 y 10");

        }
    }
}

public static void serializa(Empresa e) {
    FileOutputStream f;
    try {
        f = new FileOutputStream("PilaDePartes.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
        oos.writeObject(e);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR DE LECTURA / ESCRITURA");
    }
}

public static Empresa deserializa() {
    Empresa e = null;
    FileInputStream fe;
    try {
        fe = new FileInputStream("PilaDePartes.dat");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fe);
        e = (Empresa) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("NO SE ENCUENTRA EL ARCHIVO. COMPRUEBE LA RUTA");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("LA CLASE NO EXISTE");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR DE LECTURA / ESCRITURA");
    }
    return e;
}
```

}

Muchas gracias la verdad que entre el serializable y todas el follón ya no se donde puede estar el error.

Comment: Creo que es porque tienes creados los objetos dentro del case. tendrias que crearlos fuera y en el case usarlo si no me equivoco.

Comment: @jesuscabrera si te refieres a los métodos ``serializa`` y ``deserializa`` puede crearlos perfectamente ahí. @carlos-diaz como tienes implementado el método ``toString()`` de ``Empresa``?

Comment: Me refiero en el case 1 y case 2, al crear parte y material puedes al iniciar la clase nose si sera ese el erro, por otro lado has intentado debuguear, cuando lo intesertas y vas a  e.aniadirParte(p); que valor tiene "p", donde esta ese metodo de aniadirParte y que hace

Comment: Supongo que te refieres al `case 5` o al `case 6`, donde debería mostrar los datos ¿? Ahí haces dos llamadas a métodos de la la instancia de `Empresa`, representada por `e` en tu código, ¿podrías mostrar tu clase `Empresa` completa?

Comment: donde la muestro porque aqui me va a decir que es mucho codigo y no me va a dejar. Respecto a lo de @jesuscabrera es necesario que se creen en el case porque cada vez que llame al case se debe crear un objeto

Comment: puedes crear lo donde quieras una cosas es iniciarlizarlo o otra crearlo,  tendrias que iniciarlizarlo cuando vayas a usar uno nuevo, si depues tienes que usar el mismo objetos y lo tienes creado al principio de la clase ya solo tienes que inicializarlo y es codigo que te ahorras,  como te he dicho , debuguea y mira si e.aniadirParte(p); p tiene los valores que estas metiendo por teclado, si es asi sigue el recorrido hasta el metodo ese del la clase Empresa ...

Comment: Listo era un error en el deserializa y el serializa