# Error en un metodo y no encuentro porque

Tags: java-8

Estoy con un trabajo y tengo que crear un método que me busque los objeto que tengan 10 día de antigüedad en su atributo fecha y que su atributo estado sea pendiente.

Tengo una empresa con un arraylist de ordenes de trabajo y cada orden de trabajo tiene una serie de atributos, entre ellos una fecha de parte, una descripción etc.

Entonces busque por Internet y encontré unas idea pero me da unos errores y no encuentro el fallo. Es java 8 he usado localDate para las fechas y el ultimo método me da error y no entiendo porque.

Estos son los fallos

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Seconds
        at java.time.LocalDate.until(LocalDate.java:1614)
        at java.time.Duration.between(Duration.java:475)
        at tarea8.Empresa.trabajosPendiente(Empresa.java:83)
        at tarea8.GestionDePartes.main(GestionDePartes.java:112)
    Java Result: 1
```

Os dejo mi codigo

```
    public class Empresa implements Serializable {

    private List<ParteDeTrabajo> pilaDePartes;

    public Empresa(List<ParteDeTrabajo> pilaDePartes) {
        this.pilaDePartes = pilaDePartes;
    }

    public Empresa() {
        this.pilaDePartes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<ParteDeTrabajo> getPilaDePartes() {
        return pilaDePartes;
    }

    public void setPilaDePartes(List<ParteDeTrabajo> pilaDePartes) {
        this.pilaDePartes = pilaDePartes;
    }

    public ParteDeTrabajo buscarParte(String nombreTrabajador) {
        for (ParteDeTrabajo p1 : pilaDePartes) {
            if (p1.getNombreTrabajador().compareToIgnoreCase(nombreTrabajador) == 0) {
                return p1;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void añadirMateriales(String nombreCliente, LocalDate f,Material a) {
        for (ParteDeTrabajo p1 : pilaDePartes) {
            if (p1.getNombreCliente().compareToIgnoreCase(nombreCliente) == 0) {
                if(p1.getFechaParte().isEqual(f))
                p1.aniadirMateriales(a);
                p1.setEstado('r');
            }
        }
    }

    public String aniadirParte(ParteDeTrabajo p) {
        pilaDePartes.add(p);
        return "parte añadido";
    }

    public String borrarParte(int posicion) {
        pilaDePartes.remove(posicion);
        return "parte borrado";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String srt = "";
        for (ParteDeTrabajo p2 : pilaDePartes) {
            srt += p2.toString();
        }
        return srt;
    }

    public List<ParteDeTrabajo> trabajosPendiente() {
        List<ParteDeTrabajo> a = new ArrayList<>();
        long duracion = 0;
        LocalDate fechaHoy = LocalDate.now();
        for (ParteDeTrabajo p3 : pilaDePartes) {
            duracion = Duration.between(fechaHoy, p3.getFechaParte()).toDays();
            if (p3.getEstado() == 'p' && duracion > 10) {
                a.add(p3);
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda. Llevo ya unos días con esto y me esta dando un montón de quebraderos de cabeza trabajar con fechas.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440874/duration-ofdays-generates-unsupportedtemporaltypeexception

Comment: Puedes mostrar la clase ParteDeTrabajos

Comment: si me dices donde te la pongo si, aqui ya me he visto mono para meter la clas eempresa he tenido que escribir muchisimo nose donde meterte el otro codigo

Comment: Revisa como hacer un [mcve]. Por ejemplo, muestras un mensaje de una excepción que se lanza en el *main* de *GestionDePartes*, y nos muestras... ¿el código de la clase *Empresa*? Pon el código relevante para explicar el problema, no código que por lo que parece no tiene nada que ver con el problema.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254571/el-programa-parece-no-guardar-la-informaci%C3%B3n-o-tienen-otro-fallo-que-no-veo?noredirect=1#comment472510_254571 aqui la tienes que esta en dos preguntas distintas

Answer (score 2):

En el paquete `java.time` existe la clase `LocalDate`, que trabaja con fechas (año, mes, día). En la documentación puedes encontrar (las negritas son mías):

> This class **does not store or represent a time or time-zone**. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

La clase `LocalDate` sirve para guardar la fecha de nacimiento, la fecha de un festivo o de cualquier otro evento en el que la hora no es importante.

Si requieres guardar un momento exacto, con horas, minutos o segundos, tienes `LocalDateTime` (lo que sería el equivalente a LocalDate + horas, minutos, segundos y milisegundos), `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime` o `ZonedDateTime`, dependiendo de tus necesidades.

Otra opción en este caso sería no usar `Duration`, sino `Period`:, puesto que `Period` sólo usa años, meses y días:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2015, 2, 20);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 15);

Period period = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: La idea es buena pero no me funciona no me devuelve nada