# Parsear un Date

Tags: java

He cambiado el localDate por Date para facilitar mi trabajo viendo el no iba muy bien los metodos con localDate. el problema es uqe no se como parsear el Date. Os copio lo que tengo y me decís que debo modificar. Como setteo el valor de la variable?

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("1. Anadir un nuevo parte de trabajo");
        System.out.println("2. Añadir material al parte");
        System.out.println("3. Eliminar un parte");
        System.out.println("4. Buscar parte por nombre de trabajador");
        System.out.println("5. Listar los partes de trabaja que se hallen pendientes y tengan más 10 días de antigüedad");
        System.out.println("6. Listar  todas los partes");
        System.out.println("7. Ordenar los partes de trabajo por la fecha del parte de forma ascendente.");
        System.out.println("8. Salir");
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

        opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                ParteDeTrabajo p = new ParteDeTrabajo();
                System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: ");
                p.setNombreCliente(entrada.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha del parte en el formato (año-mes-dia): ");
                SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

                try {

                    Date date = formatter.parse(Date);
                    System.out.println(date);
                    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    p.setFechaParte(Date);

                    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del trabajador: ");
                    p.setNombreTrabajador(entrada.nextLine());

                    System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de la reparacion: ");
                    LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(entrada.nextLine());
                    p.setFechaReparacion(localDate1);

                    System.out.println("Introduzca los minutos de la reparacion: ");
                    p.setTiempoReparacion(Double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine()));

                    System.out.println("Introduzca la descripcion del arreglo: ");
                    p.setDescripcionArreglo(entrada.nextLine());
                    e.aniadirParte(p);

                    break;
```

Comment: Te lanza algun error? Por favor agregalo a tu pregunta si lo hay y sera  mas facil identificar el problema.

Comment: directamente no esta bien setteado ni parseado dalta algo

Comment: Cual es el error que recibis?

Comment: Tienes dos variables con el mismo nombre. Eso no debe ni compilar.

Comment: ya se que no compila y no esta bien por eso pregunto como se hace porque yo he sacado algo de internet y lo he adaptado a mi codigo

Comment: Tienes que tratar de entender el código, no hacer un C&P

Comment: Todo el código está mal, al principio indicas que hay que introducir una fecha pero no implementas un scanner o algo que recoja datos, tienes 2 variables con el mismo nombre dentro del mismo contexto con lo que no compilará jamás. Falta la llave de cierre del catch... como bien te dicen, intenta entender el código antes de preguntar. Quizá sea mejor que hagas un curso de java para principiantes y luego realices ejercicios.

Comment: a ver si tengo un scaner eso es parte del codigo te pongo el main entero o una parte mas grande para que lo veais. @PabloLozano no e echo copy pega pero es que no se hacerlo entonces si no se no puedo poner algo que no entiendo

Comment: Durante mucho tiempo las fechas en Java fueron un dolor de cabeza. Desde Java 8 existe el paquete `Time`, creado precisamente para facilitar el trabajo con las fechas. Cuando leo que quieres volver a `Date` me pregunto ¿por qué quieres involucionar? Si tienes problemas con `LocalDate` es porque no has entendido bien cómo funciona la nueva API de Java. La solución no es volver atrás, sino aprender a usar una herramienta que existe precisamente para simplificar el código. Sugiero que leas [esta introducción](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/paquete-java-time-2390472-esa.html).

Comment: @A.Cedano local Date es un problema en un metodo que debo usar y puesto que no consigo que el metodo funcione me es mas comodo usar Date que si rula. busca otra pregunta que tengo sobre un metodo y la veras

Comment: Lo que te quiero decir es que el hecho de que no funcione no significa que tengas que involucionar en el código. Si explicas con sencillez qué es lo que quieres hacer podemos hacer que funcione de una forma mucho más óptima y más fácil. Pero si no se tienen los elementos para ayudarte es mucho más difícil. ¿Qué tiene que hacer el método y con qué datos?

Comment: Tengo una fecha como atributo y un estado(de un objeto parte de trabajo). pues el estado tiene que estar en p  y la fecha tiene que ser 10 diaz mas antigua como mínimo que la fecha actual.

Comment: ¿Por qué no seguiste profundizando en [la solución que te sugirió @PabloLozano en otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/29967). Ese es el camino correcto, no sé por qué optas por despacharlo con un *no me funciona*, tomando así un camino más largo y complicado como es hacer involucionar el código. Con la nueva API Time es mucho más fácil calcular períodos y diferencias entre fechas. Te recomiendo que optes por una solución así, tratando de solucionar desde ahí lo que no funcione.

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma puedes convertir de String a Date:

```
//Añadir estas importaciones
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date; 

Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
String fecha;
try {
   System.out.println("Ingresa un fecha con el formato (año-mes-dia)")
   fecha = leer.nextLine(); //El usuario ingresa la fecha a parsear
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //Formato de conversión
   Date fechaConvertida = format.parse(fecha); //Se parsea la fecha
   System.out.println("La fecha convertida es: "+fechaConvertida);
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.println("No se ha podido convertir la fecha");
}
```

Enseguida otro ejemplo pero ahora incluyendo horas, minutos y segundos:

```
String fecha = "2019-04-15 13:25:00";
try {
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date fechaConvertida = format.parse(fecha);
   System.out.println("La fecha convertida es: "+fechaConvertida);
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.println("No se ha podido convertir la fecha");
}
```

Con los anteriores ejemplos resolverías tu duda puesto que, puedes acoplar el código de acuerdo a lo que requieras.

Comment: y como lo setteo?como donde le meto el set?

Comment: @carlosdiaz De la siguiente forma  p.setAtributo(fechaConvertida);

Comment: gracias ayer lo consegui terminar por fin todo el trabajo y lo entregue